# How to ping a role in a discord.js embed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to ping a specific role in a discord embed. I tried `<@652878254927249420>` but it only work on a classic message. Is it possible to ping a role in an embed ? If yes how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ping a role by its ID, you can use `<@&652878254927249420>`. There is an extra ampersand (`&`) after the at (`@`).

You can use it in embeds, but mentions won't work in the title, author, or footer, only inside `setDescription` and `addField`'s value.

[image]

If you have a role object like this, you can simply mention it using template literals:

```js
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get('652878254927249420');

message.channel.send(`I'm mentioning ${role}, ehh`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [Role#ToString](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=toString) method.

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.get("652878254927249420").toString();
```

Comment: I don't think it will work as `.get()` accepts a key not a callback fn. Did you mean `.find()`? It's either `cache.find(role => role.id === "652878254927249420")` or `cache.get("652878254927249420")`

Comment: Yep, my bad. Edited.