# How should I modify this ping timer code in discord?

Tags: javascript, discord, webhooks

I got this code on the internet, and I would like someone's help.

What modification do I make to be able to ping a role on discord at UTC -3 time.

I would like to send different messages, at different UTC-3 times, but I am not finding any such script. Could someone please help me?

```
setInterval(function(){
    // of course, replace with a real webhook token and id
    req("id channel here", "id webhook here");
}, 1200000); // interval (milliseconds) 1200000 3hours

function req(id, token) {
    const req = require("https").request({
        hostname: "discordapp.com",
        port: 443,
        path: "/api/webhooks/" + id + "/" + token,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }, function(res){
        res.setEncoding("utf8");
        res.on("data", function(ch){console.log(ch);});
    });

    req.on("error", function(e){console.error(e);});
    req.write(JSON.stringify({
        allowed_mentions: { parse: ["everyone"] },
        content: "@everyone"
    }));
    req.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In discord, you can ping roles by sending a message like so:

`<@&` + RoleID + `>`

So, enable developer mode in your settings, find the role you wish to ping, and right-click to copy its ID. You can then set your content as `<@&RoleID>` replacing RoleID as mentioned above. E.G: `<@&123456789012345678>`.

As for your UTC-3 part, I'm not sure what you mean. Can you comment with an example and I'll edit this answer accordingly.

Happy coding!

Source: [How to ping a role in a discord.js embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66953764/how-to-ping-a-role-in-a-discord-js-embed)

Comment: UTC time would be standard time for different parts of the world.
https://rggames.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Hora-Universal-Coordenada-timezone-Coordinated-universal-time-UTC.jpg

I wanted to make the bot send different messages at different times.
I just don't know if this is possible following UTC time